# When will the Java Language Specification, 4th edition be available?

Tags: java, java-7, jls

Now that the JDK 7 developer preview is out, one might think that it's time for a new JLS. After all, there have been changes to the language, albeit small ones.

I haven't found anything yet. When will a new JLS will be available, and from whence will one be able to get it?

Comment: FWIW, new versions of Java don't _always_ come with JLS updates; after all, we're on Java 6 and JLS 3.

Comment: @Lord: Java 6 didn't introduce any changes to Java language itself. but Java 7 *does* (i.e. switch on strings, resource closing, ...)!

Comment: @Peter, indeed. I'm not saying there won't be one -- it was just a comment, not an answer -- just that the schedule might not match up with 7's release as much one might think.

Comment: @Lord: I'm just pointing out that it is reasonable to expect new JLS for Java7, although as you say, they may not be coming at the same time.

Comment: Here is an update from JSR 901 maintainance leader: http://blogs.sun.com/abuckley/entry/maintenance_review_of_the_java1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be interested in both of these:

[JSR 901: Java Language Specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=901)
[JSR 924: Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=924)

Not surprisingly, both of them have recent draft reviews...

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE Feb 18, 2012:
As described at https://blogs.oracle.com/abuckley/en_US/entry/jls7_and_jvms7_online, the Java SE 7 Editions of the Java Language
Specification and the JVM Specification are now available at
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/ in both PDF and HTML form.

---

There are 3 locations from which you can download the Java Language
Specification (JLS), 4th edition (more precisely, not "4th edition" but "Java SE 7 edition").

A relatively old draft is part of JSR 901 (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=901).  It is missing discussion of some of
the new language features, such as those of JSR 334, Project Coin (http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=334).

JSR 336 (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336) contains an Annex 3 (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/java_se-7-final-spec/java_se-7-final-annex-3.zip)
that has four different versions of the JLS:  a full version with and
without changebars, and a normative-only (1/3 shorter, lacking some
examples and explanations) version with and without changebars.  JSR 336's
Annex 3 also has 2 versions of the JVMS (with and without changebars).

The best source is to get the JLS from
the Java SE Specifications download
page (http://download.oracle.com/javase/cmn/spec_index.html) (direct link
to JLS PDF: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/specs/jls/JLS-JavaSE7.pdf).  This
version is slightly updated, compared to the JSR 336 version.  Only one
variety is available:  the full specification without changebars.

As of now (August 4, 2011), JLS 4th edition is not available in printed
form, nor is it available from http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/ where
the first three editions are available for download.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question about when the fourth edition will be available — actually, strictly speaking, that question is [considered off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56480/are-strongly-on-topic-questions-about-predicting-the-future-allowed), though I don't have a problem with it — but I'm confident that you'll be able to get a copy at [Oracle's JLS page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).

That page currently offers nearly complete* electronic copies of the first three editions for free. It also links to the third edition's page on Amazon.com, so I'm also confident that you'll be able to buy paper copies at major booksellers, if you're into that sort of thing.

<sup>* *The online version differs from the print version in minor ways, primarily the absence of quotations due to copyright issues.*</sup>